# Queue items showing duplicate emails in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: email, duplicates, queue, dynamics-crm

My queue item is showing duplicate emails. I've checked in CRM but there is only one record exists. Actually, we have a workflow that route the emails to the queue of the team of Owning user. So I checked workflow process session and it was triggered once to push the same email to the queue. There is also no plugin registered for this routing.

Any idea how can I restrict queue items to shown as duplicate?

**UDPATE 1:**
The complete process is whenever email is landed in CRM. Checks its owner, if it is team then push this email to the queue of that team. Otherwise push the email to queue of Unresolved Senders. For unresolved case, I've check and found that the duplicated email don't fall there but in team's queue only.

Comment: What is your Trigger for Workflow. I believe your workflow is somehow firing twice but in log you get only latest.
How about you try your workflow only on create for testing and see how many times Email is been sent.

Comment: The workflow is at create event of email,

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain your complete process. It does not make sense to fire workflow on create of email rather set trigger as for example when opportunity is created or field is updated.